# cassandra opscenter toggles between "agents failed to connect" and "all agents connected" every two or three minutes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, opscenter, nodetool

[image: **enter image description here**]

[image]

cassandra opscenter toggles between "agents failed to connect" and "all agents connected" every two or three minutes? I am not sure what is happening. It says all agents are connected for two to three minutes and then it says it has trouble connecting with the agents as shown in the pictures above. Also I checked all the conf file and the ssl is not used just like it is in the default. This is through AWS amazon.

Comment: worth noting opscenter doesn't yet support cassandra 2.2 as of OpsCenter 5.2.3

Comment: can you point me where it says that? Also what is most stable and recent cassandra version does OpsCenter support?

Comment: http://docs.datastax.com/en/upgrade/doc/upgrade/opscenter/opscCompatibility.html OpsCenter is released with versions of datastax enterprise. Since there hasn't been a DSE release for 3.0 yet (2.2 is kinda a pre-3.0). 2.1 and 2.0 are the most recently supported.

Comment: I am having a similar issue and am using the full DSE with Cassandra bundled. I have even tried updating datastax-agent-xxxx manually and this hasn't made a difference. This is with DSE 4.8 Opscenter and datastax-agent 5.2.3 and Cassandra 2.1 (as bundled with DSE) Worth noting that my cluster seems to work fine with DevCenter..